# Can't import system.web.ui.design under .net framework 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am moving a VB.net class from a project using .net 2.0 to a project using .net 4.5
In the class is a `Imports System.Web.UI.Design`, however, in the 4.5 project this statement shows up with a green squiggly line under it and the mouseover text says: "Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Web.UI.Design' doesn't contain any public members or cannot be found."

I have added the System.Design.dll as a reference to the project and in the Object Browser, I can see the System.Web.UI.Design namespace. I have verified that the system.design.dll exists in Windows/Microsoft.Net/Framework/v4.0.30319 and Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/.NETFramework/v4.5 directories.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

In Windows/Assembly, I only see the 2.0.0.0 version of the assembly, however, Add Reference in VS shows the version I added as 4.0.0.0. Tried dropping the dll from the v4.0.30319 directory into windows/assembly and using the gacutil. While gacutil said the assembly was added, it still didn't appear in Windows/Assembly.

Comment: Just import the .NET 4 version.